# Polynomial long division does not return expected result

Tags: polynomials

When I run the long division algorithm on the `f=x-y` and `F={xy+x+1,xy+y+1}`, I get the quotients `0,0`, and the remainder is `r=x-y`. I understand that this is the correct result according to the algorithm, but I can also see that `x-y = 1*(xy+x+1) + (-1)*(xy+y+1)+0` and this result differs from the long division result but seems more logical to me.

Why is that? Isn't the long division supposed to return quotients that create input `f` as a combination of `F` polynomials?

Thanks in advance

Python code:

```
>>> from sympy.abc import x,y
>>> from sympy.polys.polytools import reduced
>>> reduced(x-y, [x*y+x+1, x*y+y+1])
([0, 0], x - y)
```

Comment: "Isn't the long division supposed to return quotients that create input `f` as a combination of `F` polynomials?" It did exactly that, but the answer is not unique. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56648

Comment: @DavidK  Oh, I didn't realize that. Thank you.